# Why is glass shadow blocky in viewport render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency, shadows

Raytraced shadow was set to be smooth (Point lamp: 6 samples, 2 size) and solid material produces fine results, but enabling any transparency gives strange blocky parts inside smooth area.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Appears to be a viewport issue. Render is fine. You shouldn't rely on the viewport for render view. (I am aware that this doesn't answer anything.)

Comment: I was thinking about viewport rendering to radically reduce rendertime, but can't stand such things